# How to correctly stack sklearn pipeline with custom selector

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to use the `StackingClassifier` class from `sklearn` to create an ensamble learner.

Specifically, I have two different types of data: 2D images and classical tabular data. I would like to use a MLP classifier for the 2D images and a RandomForest classifier for the tabular data. Then I would like to use a RandomForest classifier to combine the predictions from the two models above into my final predicitions.

Since there is no way to provide separate training data to an instance of `StackingClassifier` I have resorted to the following trick: I have created two `Pipeline`s with a custom selector that return a value from a dictionary. While I can fit and predict the pipelines separately, I have a `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples` when I try to fit and predict the stacked model.

Below the code that I have used:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

#Customized Selector 
class DictionarySelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, in_dict, key):

        self.in_dict = in_dict
        self.key = key
        
    def fit(self, x, y = None):
        return(self)
    
    def transform(self, key):
        return(self.in_dict[self.key])
    
    
        

# Generate some example data 
# For demonstration purposes, I'm using the Iris dataset
data = load_iris()
X_images = data.data[:, :2]  # Let's say that these are my images
X_vector = data.data[:, 2:]  # Unidimensional vector 
y = data.target  # Target classes (3 classes)

# Split the data into train and test sets
X_images_train, X_images_test, X_vector_train, X_vector_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X_images, X_vector, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42
)

# Define the MLP for images
image_model = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(64, 32), activation="relu", max_iter=1000)

# Define the Random Forest for vectors
vector_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, criterion="gini", max_depth=None)
#Create dict with the two data types
in_dict = {'images' : X_images_train, 'vector' : X_vector_train}
#MLP pipeline for images
pipe_images = Pipeline([
    ('select', DictionarySelector(in_dict, 'images')),
    ('clf', image_model)
])

#check: it works
print(pipe_images.fit(X_images_train, y_train).predict(X_images_test))

#features pipeline
pipe_vector = Pipeline([
    ('select', DictionarySelector(in_dict, 'vector')),
    ('clf', vector_model)
])
#check: it works
print(pipe_images.fit(X_vector_train, y_train).predict(X_vector_test))

# Create a stacked model
stacked_model = StackingClassifier(
    estimators=[
        ("image_mlp", pipe_images),
        ("vector_rf", pipe_vector),
    ],
    final_estimator=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100),
)

#The stacked model throw the ValueError
stacked_model.fit(in_dict, y_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine the tabular and image data into a single matrix of `n_samples x (tabular features + image features)`. Then create tabular/image pipelines such that the tabular one pulls out the tabular columns, and the image pipeline pulls out the image columns. That way you can supply the same data to both estimators, and they will internally deal with selecting the columns they need before running their classifier. I've modified the code to this effect.

The steps are:

- Image data is shaped into an `n_samples x n_pixels` matrix
- Tabular data is shaped into an `n_samples x n_features` matrix
- The two matrices are concatenated into a wider matrix that has all the columns
- The tabular pipeline is [tabular column selector -> tabular classifier]. The column selector step is a `ColumnTransformer` that selects the tabular columns and discards the rest. Similar definitions for the image pipeline.

The tabular, image, and stacked classifiers all work with the same input data matrix (`X_train`, `y_train`).

Output:

```py
Checking pipe_image | score=0.900
  [1 0 2 1 2 0 1 2 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 1 2 0 1 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0] 

Checking pipe_tabular | score=1.000
  [1 0 2 1 1 0 1 2 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 1 2 0 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0] 

Stacked accuracy: 1.000
```

The orange boxes are the individual pipelines for the tabular/image data, and the blue outline is the stacking classifier.

[image]

---

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

np.random.seed(0)

# Generate some example data 
# For demonstration purposes, I'm using the Iris dataset
data = load_iris()
X_images = data.data[:, :2]  # Let's say that these are my images
X_images_flat = X_images.reshape(len(X_images), -1) #flatten each sample from 2D to 1D if required

X_tabular = data.data[:, 2:]  # Unidimensional vector of tabular data 
y = data.target  # Target classes (3 classes)

X_images_and_tabular = np.concatenate([X_images_flat, X_tabular], axis=1)
images_col_indices = np.arange(X_images_flat.shape[1])
tabular_col_indices = np.arange(X_images_flat.shape[1], X_images_and_tabular.shape[1])

#
# Make 2 column selectors
#  Each transformer will "passthrough" the image or tabular columns and
#   "drop" the remaining columns, depending on whether it is selecting the
#   image data or tabular data
#
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

image_columns_selector = ColumnTransformer(
    [('image_columns_selector', 'passthrough', images_col_indices)],
    remainder='drop'
)

tabular_columns_selector = ColumnTransformer(
    [('tabular_columns_selector', 'passthrough', tabular_col_indices)],
    remainder='drop'
)

# Split the data into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X_images_and_tabular, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42
)

# Define the MLP for images
image_model = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(64, 32), activation="relu", max_iter=3000)

# Define the Random Forest for tabular data
tabular_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, criterion="gini")

#MLP pipeline for images
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
pipe_image = make_pipeline(image_columns_selector, image_model)
image_pipe_acc = accuracy_score(
    y_test,
    pipe_image.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
)
print(f'Checking pipe_image | score={image_pipe_acc:.3f}\n ', pipe_image.predict(X_test), '\n')

#features pipeline
pipe_tabular = make_pipeline(tabular_columns_selector, tabular_model)
tabular_pipe_acc = accuracy_score(
    y_test,
    pipe_tabular.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
)
print(f'Checking pipe_tabular | score={tabular_pipe_acc:.3f}\n ', pipe_tabular.predict(X_test), '\n')

# Create a stacked model
stacked_model = StackingClassifier(
    estimators=[
        ("image_mlp", pipe_image),
        ("tabular_rf", pipe_tabular),
    ],
    final_estimator=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100),
)

#The stacked model throw the ValueError
stacked_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(
    'Stacked accuracy:',
    '%5.3f' % stacked_model.score(X_test, y_test)
)
```